# Get last modification of a resource file - revisited

Tags: java, file, netbeans, resources

I have a NetBeans Desktop application with the following folder structure:
myProject
   Source Packages
       myClasses
          ClassA
          ClassB
          ...
       Data
          datafile1.xml
          datafile2.xml
          ....

Now, I want to get the last changed date of these resource files - say, datafile1.xml etc.
I have tried it by the following code lines (as in a previous thread):

class LastChangeDate...
...
URL url = ClassA.class.getResource(pathname);
return (new Date(url.openConnection().getLastModified()).toString());
...

It shows not the date I see by right-clicking the datafile1.xml in NetBeans GUI, but actually the last compile date of the project - for all resource files the same date.
Please tell me if I have made a mistake with my thinking...

Comment: All compilation processes copy files, so you probably can't rely on those dates.  Perhaps if you describe why you need it, someone can suggest an alternative.  (Technically, you might be able to modify NetBeans' internal Ant scripts so they do `<copy preservelastmodified="true">`, but wanting a custom compilation is usually a hint that there's a better way.)

Comment: Thanks first. My workflow is to import my data daily or weekly into my package. I want to signal for the user, which import data version creates the displayed data in my GUI. And again: by right-clicking on the properties in NetBeans I can see this date clearly and right.

Comment: Whatever process you use to import the data should store a timestamp or an incrementing version number with the data.  If the data is under version control, a substitutable keyword (like Subversion's `$Revision$`) might also work.